# z-index наложение

Tags: css, css3

Помогите разобраться, мне нужно чтобы при scale любого элемента его z-index был всегда выше остальных. Сейчас же z-index работает как обычно, элемент который ниже в DOM имеет выше приоритет. https://codepen.io/brezze/pen/aEjOdv

```
<div class="block">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="item item-orange">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="item item-blue">2</div>
        <div class="item item-black">3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.item-blue {
  height: 50%;
  background-color: navy;
  width: 100%;
}

.item-orange {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 300px;
}

.item-black {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 50%;
}

.item {
  transition: all .2s ease;
   position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.item:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё просто, добавьте

```
.item:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  z-index:100;  /* добавили */
}
```

Comment: да уж, что-то я совсем заработался. Спасибо

Comment: @DenisDenis если помогло, тогда отметьте ответом, пожалуйста